# Graphql in retrofit Android result in 400 error

Tags: android, graphql, retrofit

I have tried to implement Graphql API in Android using Retrofit. I'm getting 400 error, is my query format is wrong? I have posted my code below. The same query works fine in postman, but not in the code.

```
object GraphQLInstance {
private const val BASE_URL: String = "https://myUrl.amazonaws.com/"
val graphQLService: GraphQLService by lazy {
Retrofit
.Builder()
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
.build().create(GraphQLService::class.java)

}

}

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("graphql/")
suspend fun getEquipmentList(  @Header("Authorization") token: String?, @Header("x-api-key") apiKey: String?, @Header("x-schema") schema: String?, @Body body: String): Response\<String\>

private fun getAllEquipments() {
val retrofit = GraphQLInstance.graphQLService
val paramObject = JSONObject()
paramObject.put("query", " {\\n" +
" \\t"operationName": "MyQuery",\\n" +
" \\t"variables": {},\\n" +
" \\t"query": "query MyQuery {\\n  listEquipment(query: {query: \\"{              }\\", page: 1, search: \\"\\", size: 25}) {\\n    items {\\n      id\\n      name\\n      image\\n      equipment_type_name\\n      category_name\\n      property_name\\n      specific_location\\n      manufacturer_name\\n      model_name\\n      age\\n    }\\n    page\\n    size\\n    total\\n  }\\n}"\\n" +
" }")
GlobalScope.launch {
try {
val response = retrofit.getEquipmentList(deliveryToken,apiKey,"web",paramObject.toString())
Log.e("response code \>\>",response.code().toString());
if (response.code() == 400) {
Log.v("Error code 400",response.errorBody().toString()) 
 }
            Log.e("response ", response.raw().toString())
            Log.e("response body", response.body().toString())
        }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note but for GraphQL on Android I recommend Apollo client: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/

Comment: Have you tested the query in GraphiQL or Apollo Studio? Also +1 on @KenWolf's note - using Apollo client is way easier. Debugging raw POSTs is painful.

Comment: I have used Apollo library instead of retrofit.